# Powershell - RegEx matching form elements by fullname via Get-Variable

Tags: powershell

How can you use Get-Variable pipe to operate on specific WinForm objects that match a RegEx to the Fullname property? Attempts to use `Where-Object {($_).GetType().FullName -match '^System\.Windows\.Forms'}` fail.

In the example below `($TestButton).GetType().FullName` does return `System.Windows.Forms.Button`. But referencing with `($_).GetType().FullName` returns `System.Management.Automation.PSVariable`.

Why does this not work, does a near or equivalent exist?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form;
$form.ClientSize                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,100);
$form.text                       = "Form";
$TestButton                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$TestButton.text                    = "Test"
$TestButton.width                   = 85
$TestButton.height                  = 30
$TestButton.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,0)
$TestButton.Font                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',12)

($TestButton).GetType().FullName # This gives output
Get-Variable |
#Where-Object {($_).GetType().FullName -match '^System\.Windows\.Forms'} | # Line disabled for debugging only.
Foreach-Object{
                    $form.controls.Add($_) # Not working - obvious why due to output below - nothing matches...
                    ($_).GetType().FullName# due to System.Management.Automation.PSVariable
}
$form.controls.AddRange(@($TestButton)) # Works as expected. 
[void]$form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work, just as intended. You're just working with different object types.

`$TestButton` is an object of type `System.Windows.Forms.Button`

When you run `Get-Variable`, it returns objects of type `System.Management.Automation.PSVariable`

if you run `Get-Variable -Name TestButton` You'll see that by default, it returns Name and a value field. This is the name of the variable, and the value of said variable.

What I assume you're looking to do, is extract the *value* of that variable, and get the type of the actual value. You would do this like this

```
(Get-Variable -Name TestButton | % Value).GetType().Fullname
```

So for your `Get-Variable` pipe

```
Get-Variable |
  Where-Object {$_.value -is [System.Windows.Forms.Button]} | 
  Foreach-Object{
    $form.controls.Add($_.value) 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
Get-Variable | where {$_.Value -is [system.windows.forms.button]}
```

or

```
Get-Variable | where {$_.Value.gettype().fullname -match 'system\.windows\.forms'}
```